# Add paths to environsment and launch and app

Tags: batch, environment-variables, vbscript

I want to add some shell actions to execute some apps. These apps require some environment set from complex batch files.
That is, my action should call:

```
c:\xxx\SetPath.bat
c:\yyy\startApp.exe
```

The problem is that SetPath.bat opends up cmd.exe and sets environment AND stays inside cmd.exe
But I need to set that environment and then execute an app. On top of that the app is a gui app, so it would be nice to avoid showing up console when I run the environment batch file (I can use hidcon for that).

The gui app is cygwin shell (mintty) and at login there I also need to add some action :) but it's not a big deal.

I've seen similar stuff done with vbs, but I can't recall where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, when you run a batch-file from another batch-file, control is permanently transferred to the second one. If you want it to run and then return, use the `call` command.

Normally, when you run a command in a batch-file, the batch-file waits for the command to finish before moving to the next line. To make it continue to the next line without waiting, use the `start` command.

So you need to change your `.bat` file to read:

```
call  c:\xxx\setpath.bat
start c:\yyy\startapp.exe
```

It calls `setpath` which runs, then it returns and starts `startapp`, then continues to the next line, which in this case is the end-of-file so the batch-file ends and the console window closes, leaving the GUI program runnning.

Comment: Thanks. Actually there was no problem and I thought that solution should be something similar to include ('.') operator in bash to prevent setpath.bat for getting stuck, but it was simply a shortcut that used `cmd /k' and I simply removed that part. The only issue remains is the hidcon part.